Maximum recursion depth exceeded when using ColBERT reranker for Llama 3
I am looking to deploy ColBERT reranker for my RAG pipeline, with a T4 GPU (the LLM that I am using is Meta-LLaMa-3-8B-Instruct, which has already been quantized to 4bit):
import torch
from llama_index.llms.huggingface import HuggingFaceLLM
from transformers import BitsAndBytesConfig

quantization_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(
    load_in_4bit=True,
    bnb_4bit_compute_dtype=torch.float16,
    bnb_4bit_quant_type="nf4",
    bnb_4bit_use_double_quant=True,
)

llm = HuggingFaceLLM(
    model_name="meta-llama/Meta-Llama-3-8B-Instruct",
    system_prompt=system_prompt,
    query_wrapper_prompt=query_wrapper_prompt,
    context_window=8192,
    max_new_tokens=512,
    model_kwargs={
        "token": hf_token,
        "torch_dtype": torch.bfloat16,  
        "quantization_config": quantization_config
    },
    generate_kwargs={
        "do_sample": False,
        "temperature": 0.05,
        "top_p": 0.3,

    },
    tokenizer_name="meta-llama/Meta-Llama-3-8B-Instruct",
    tokenizer_kwargs={"token": hf_token},
    stopping_ids=stopping_ids,
)

My ColBERT reranker using Meta-LLaMa-3-8B-Instruct as model and tokenizer as well, with the quantized version:
from llama_index.postprocessor.colbert_rerank import ColbertRerank

colbert_reranker = ColbertRerank(
    top_n=5,
    model=llm,
    tokenizer="meta-llama/Meta-Llama-3-8B-Instruct",
    keep_retrieval_score=True,
)

However, when I am running the reranker, I got this error: RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the repr of an object. From here, it seems that the problem is with Transformers, however I am not sure about whether it could be a problem to my pipeline.
So, how to resolve this problem to the reranker in this situation?
